# adding 2 samples in R

Tags: r

[image: These are the 2 samples I want to join]I have two samples called ran_user and ran_nonuser,
I want to combine them and have used paste() but it makes them a string of characters and the first entry is "ran_user sample one.  ran_nonuser sample one" etc

how can I add the two samples together and make it numeric

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want them added into one long string of numbers so..... 30, 1376, 67, 1668, 115, 500, 20, 967, etc

Comment: A single, long string of numbers would be ```"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7"``` but I assume you need a vector, i.e. ```c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)```? (A string is not numeric but R interprets it as text.)

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to combine your samples? This remains completely unclear from you question.
Anyways, here are a few options, since we can only guess what you want:

```
# Here, I create some example data. Of course, you would use your data:
ran_user <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
ran_nonuser <- c(5, 6, 7, 8)
```

The following simply combines both of your vectors to a single vector where the values of `ran_user` come first and all other values are appended at the end:

```
new <- c(ran_user, ran_nonuser)
new
# Result: c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
```

If you want to combine the samples in a matrix, you can use the following in order to have the sample vectors as columns:

```
new <- cbind(ran_user, ran_nonuser)
new
```

If you want to have the sample vectors as rows of a matrix, use `rbind()` instead:

```
new <- rbind(ran_user, ran_nonuser)
new
```

The following produces a single vector where the first value of `ran_user` is followed by the first value of `ran_nonuser` and so on:

```
new <- rbind(ran_user, ran_nonuser)
new_v <- as.vector(new)
new_v
```

I think the last option looks most like what you would get from `paste()` (though with numeric values, as you said you need.)

Comment: Aside from `c(A, B)` I dont think any of these will produce a desired result in the OP data -  the user/nonuser vectors are different sizes (unlike your sample data), so the other approaches will recycle the shorter vector and produce (possibly) undesirable results. It's still unclear from the OP though if they would want to recycle the vector.

Comment: @jpsmith Right, I assumed the vectors would be of equal length, since the OP pasted them in pairs already. However, some screenshot was added now, which shows different lengths. It is indeed unclear what the expected output should be.

Answer (score 0):

Could you detail a bit more? Some possibilities are:

```
set.seed(1234)

# sample 1 (vector)
s1 <- rnorm(5)

# sample 2 (another vector)
s2 <- rpois(5)

# to a data frame
data.frame(
  sample1 = s1,
  sample2 = s2
)

# to a single vector
c(s1, s2)

# to a list
list(
  sample1 = s1,
  sample2 = s2
)
```